# Export .sql dump

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, dump

I have to make a dump file with the extension .sql, what is the correct way to do this? I am using Oracle database Express Edition 10g. Would this work fine if I enter it in the cmd?

```
expdp system/system_password full=Y EXCLUDE=SCHEMA:\"LIKE \'APEX_%\'\",SCHEMA:\"LIKE \'FLOWS_%\'\" directory=DUMP_DIR dumpfile=DB1.sql logfile=expdpDB10G.log
```

Answer (score 0):

expdp creates a dump file, which can only be used by impdp and cannot be run as a SQL script, so it doesn't make sense to name it with the `.sql` extension.

I prefer to name it with something like `.dmp` so that it's clearer what it contains.

Comment: and how could i make a .sql file?

Comment: well, some people use SQL Developer, but me, I'm old school. Notepad :)